# Add custom time to video frames using ffmpeg

Tags: java, time, ffmpeg, timestamp, pipe

I am using ffmpeg to encode raw pixels data (bgr32) into a video file.

Pixels data is being sent from java application to ffmpeg stdin pipe.

I am looking for a way to add a timestamp overlay to each frame in the encoded video file.

It looks like there is a way to add a timestamp of current time.

The instructions could be found here: http://einar.slaskete.net/2011/09/05/adding-time-stamp-overlay-to-video-stream-using-ffmpeg/

Examples of code from that site are this:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -s 640x480 -r 30 -vf \
"drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ttf-dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
text='\%T': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=460" -vcodec libx264 -vb 2000k \
-preset ultrafast -f mp4 output.mp4
```

And this:

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -input_format mjpeg -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 \
-vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf: \
text='%{localtime\:%T}': fontcolor=white@0.8: x=7: y=700" -vcodec libx264 \
-preset veryfast -f mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y output.mp4
```

Video files that I am encoding were captured few days ago and I need to add a custom time to each frame. For example 12/12/2013 11:11:45 and not the current time.

Is it possible to do something like it using ffmpeg?

Answer (score 0):

There is [a `drawtext` filter](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext-1) when compiled with the `--enable-libfreetype` configuration. If you don't have this, you have to [compile ffmpeg yourself](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) – not terribly complicated though.

The easiest syntax would be:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -vf 'drawtext=fontsize=15:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text=LONG_LINE:y=100:x=100' output.mp4
```

This positions the text at 100 pixels offset from the top left corner. You can then use [the `enable` option](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) to specify a text for a certain frame, e.g. to show a text only for frame `123`, you'd use:

```
drawtext=enable='eq(n,123)':fontsize=15:fontfile=FreeSerif.ttf:text='I':y=100:x=100
```

So, of course you have to procedurally generate the command to show a certain string for only a certain time.

---

Another idea would be to [burn subtitles into the video](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20burn%20subtitles%20into%20the%20video) from a pre-generated subtitle file.

Comment: Burning subtitles is an interesting ides. Thanks. It looks that there are no other options to pass text information for each frame using pipe or pregenerated file.

Comment: You can [use `-filter_complex_script`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Advanced-options) to supply the path to a script containing filter options, but that's all I can think of.